# Inserting into multiple tables using a single query in preparestatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is my code

```
String query = "insert into Branch (CompanyID,BranchName,BranchAddress,Email,Phone,ContactPerson) values (?,?,?,?,?,?);insert into Activities(EmployeeID,ActivityType,Activities) values (?,?,?)";

            // System.out.println(mobile);//BranchName      | BranchAddress      | Email      | Phone      | ContactPerson

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, compid);
            pstmt.setString(2, name);
            pstmt.setString(3, address);
            pstmt.setString(4, email);
            pstmt.setString(5, mobile);
            pstmt.setString(6, contactperson);
            pstmt.setString(7, empid);
            pstmt.setString(8, acttype);
            pstmt.setString(9, activity);
            System.out.println(query+"-----"+acttype);
            pstmt.execute();
            status = true;
```

If I insert without dynamic values it gets inserted otherwise I get the below error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into Activities(EmployeeID,ActivityType,Activities) values ('6','createbr' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into Activities(EmployeeID,ActivityType,Activities) values ('6','createbr' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155).........
```

How can I overcome this ??? I am able to insert using this statement below

```
insert into Branch (CompanyID,BranchName,BranchAddress,Email,Phone,ContactPerson) values ('1','sample','11 cross','fakemail@gmail.com','5467897656','Deigo');insert into Activities(EmployeeID,ActivityType,Activities) values ('6','createdbranch','cearted branch sample');
```

But I want it to be dynamic.Please help

Comment: One way to overcome this is to run two separate insert statements using separate preparedstatements. Any reason you want them in one? You could get the same effect with two statement in a transaction. I haven't found any documentation that you can do two parameterized insert statements in a single statement.

Comment: @SamM - Is it a good practice to open and close two preparedstatement?

Comment: @SamM - Is it a good practice to open and close two preparedstatement?

Comment: yes, it is standard practice to use multiple preparedstatements. Remember to close it in between calls. And you can wrap them in a single database transaction if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allowMultiQueries=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true` needs to be added to the connection params to allow execution of multiple queries.

For example, the `url` may be like:

```
jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnnnn/db_name?allowMultiQueries=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&user=xxxx&password=yyyy
```

Comment: - Thanks it worked ..but I did not add rewriteBatchedStatements=true, will it affect any thing?

Comment: It is fine. `rewriteBatchedStatements` sometimes may be faster. But for your case, I think there is no difference.